# Postman API testing for my test cases

Tags: api, testing, postman

I have 300 test cases for an API. I want to do it on Postman, but writing 300 requests with different inputs does not seem logical. My test cases are like;

```
Input1   -   Input2   -   Input2   -   Expected Result

..dt1..  -   ..dt5..  -   ..dt8..  -   Fail
..dt2..  -   ..dt6..  -   ..dt8..  -   Success
..dt3..  -   ..dt5..  -   ..dt9..  -   Fail
```

Can I give possible entries for each input field and let postman do a combination of all 3 possibilities. Or I can give cases 1 by 1 like this and check results.

Comment: I don’t really understand the question, would you be able to clarify what you’re wanting to do. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to make a data driven test using postman, but I don't think you can do it with postman you have to make sure. Instead you can simulate the request using Postman and export it as a web test then use for example visual studio web test to make it data driven. 
see 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slange/2008/05/23/creating-a-data-driven-web-test-against-a-web-service/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeking to simulate 300 test cases using much less api for different input. So you can try using a code-base api testing framework like Rest Assured. There you can store your api(s) in one class, and you can write your test cases in another class(es), and can use the test data on your test classes. Then you can organise your test cases like this.

Hope this will help your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way - using pre-request script.
Basically, you'll need to enter the input data into the pre request script, and use the postman runner to run it 300 times.
Here's a documentation to help you with this:
https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/collection/9215231-25b72aab-2c6a-4941-832d-dd47e142ff2a?ctx=documentation